# Best practice for getting RDS password to docker container on ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs

I am using Postgres Amazon RDS and Amazon ECS for running my docker containers.
The question is. What is the best practice for getting the username and password for the RDS database into the docker container running on ECS?

I see a few options:

- Build the credentials into docker image. I don't like this since then everyone with access to the image can get the password.
- Put the credentials in the userdata of the launch configuration used by the autoscaling group for ECS. With this approach all docker images running on my ECS cluster has access to the credentials. I don't really like that either. That way if a blackhat finds a security hole in any of my services (even services that does not use the database) he will be able to get the credentials for the database.
- Put the credentials in a S3 and control the limit the access to that bucket with a IAM role that the ECS server has. Same drawbacks as putting them in the userdata.
- Put the credentials in the Task Definition of ECS. I don't see any drawbacks here.

What is your thoughts on the best way to do this? Did I miss any options?

regards,
Tobias

Comment: Hi Tobias, I want to do the same thing as you, use Postgres Amazon RDS + ECS +Docker. I followed this out-dated post https://blog.camunda.com/post/2015/06/deploy-camunda-bpm-docker-image-with/ But I cannot connect to the database from ECS see my post https://serverfault.com/questions/925671/java-sql-sqlexception-driverorg-postgresql-driver-returned-null-for-u?rq=1  Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong ? How did you connect to RDS from ECS ? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Building it into the container is never recomended. Makes it hard to distribute and change.

Putting it into the ECS instances does not help your containers to use it. They are isolated and you'd end up with them on all instances instead of just where the containers are that need them.

Putting them into S3 means you'll have to write that functionality into your container. And it's another place to have configuration.

Putting them into your task definition is the recommended way. You can  use the `environment` portion for this. It's flexible. It's also how PaaS offerings like Heroku and Elastic Beanstalk use DB connection strings for Ruby on rails and other services. Last benefit is it makes it easy to use your containers against different databases (like dev, test, prod) without rebuilding containers or building weird functionality

Comment: Thank you. We ended up putting them in the task definition as you suggested and it works like a charm.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but shouldn't we just be using IAM roles to grant access? The EC2 Instance carrying this cluster could have the permission to read/write to RDS if it's in Amazon's ecosystem. As far as I understand it, you shouldn't ever have to hard code credentials - even as an environment variable.

Comment: Environment variables aren't hardcoded, especially in task definitions, you can iterate them because they're not in the binary (the container). Also IAM doesn't allow you access to RDS. RDS is a hosted database, you still connect to it with a connection string (url, port, username, password)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer recommends configuring environment variables in the task definition.  This configuration is buried deep in the ECS web console. You have to:

1. Navigate to Task Definitions
2. Select the correct task and revision
3. Choose to create a new revision (not allowed to edit existing)
4. Scroll down to the container section and select the correct container
5. Scroll down to the Env Variables section
6. Add your configuration
7. Save the configuration and task revision
8. Choose to update your service with the new task revision

[This tutorial has screenshots](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/ecs-rds-tutorial/#step-23-set-up-amazon-ecs) that illustrate where to go.

Full disclosure: This tutorial features containers from Bitnami and I work for Bitnami. However the thoughts expressed here are my own and not the opinion of Bitnami.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you, now you could do the other (almost identical) answer you left yesterday?

Comment: I see a valueFrom type of value, anyone know if this can be used to retrieve the values from rds itself or from some type of keyVault style service?

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, while putting credentials into environment variables in your task definition is certainly convenient, it's generally regarded as not particularly secure -- other processes can access your environment variables.

I'm not saying you can't do it this way -- I'm sure there are lots of people doing exactly this, but I wouldn't call it "best practice" either. Using Amazon Secrets Manager or SSM Parameter Store is definitely more secure, although getting your credentials out of there for use has its own challenges and on some platforms those challenges may make configuring your database connection much harder.

Still -- it seems like a good idea that anyone running across this question be at least aware that using the task definition for secrets is ... shall way say ... frowned upon?

Comment: where else do you want to put the rds credentials? If you use ssm-secure Parameter what could here be improved? Have you come across a better solution? cheers A

Comment: I'm saying that the solutions for secrets, be the platform-specific like SSM Parameter Store or Secrets Manager, or platform-agnostic like Hashicorp Vault, are regarded as good choices, although less simple. Environment variables are simple and easy to use, but not considered particularly secure.